# WPF: DateTime Picker Selection Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

Here i used WPF date picker without any style or control template. When i goes to previous month and comes back to same month, i seen some other day is in **Enable state**. And also i tried some other control template from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468215%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but issue is still exists.Here i attached screenshot for reference.Tool Used VS2010

Steps to Reproduce:

1.Today Date '4' is highlighted in December Month.

2.Go back to October Month and come back to December month u can able to see '8' is enable state before that it is in disable state.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem exists in the default style of CalendarDayButton. (You can get it by right clicking on WPF Designer and choose Edit Additional templates->CalendarDayButtonStyle) There is a VisualStateGroup called **ActiveStates** in this style. If you look at the **Active** State, it is empty.

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="ActiveStates">
    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
    <VisualState x:Name="Active" />
    <VisualState x:Name="Inactive">
        <Storyboard>
            <ColorAnimation Duration="0"
                            To="#FF777777"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText" />
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

So when you change the month to previous and come back, the date slot, which acted for Today date previously, has to change its state from **Today** State to **Active** State. Since the active state is empty, the Foreground property will fallback to the one which applied directly to the element, which is dark color (Black).

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="NormalText"
                TextElement.Foreground="#FF333333"
                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                Margin="5,1,5,1"
                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
```

This is the reason, the particular slot appears to be dark, even though it is next month. Now the solution is to add a valid storyboard to **Active** state (target to dark color), instead of leave it empty. And change the default foreground color applied to the ContentPresenter to light color. Now it will work good. I provided the download link to get the bug free style.

[Download CalendarDayButtonStyle](https://db.tt/XMsw5JY9)

```
<Calendar CalendarDayButtonStyle="{DynamicResource CalendarDayButtonStyle}" />
```